# Resolving promise object before MySQL INSERT

Tags: javascript, mysql, promise

Using the mysql2/promise library, one of my objects partly consists of unresolved promises from previous SELECT statements.

When inserting, I get an incorrect integer value error message because the promises have not been resolved. What would be an elegant way to resolve the contained promises?

```
let insertObj = {
  author: this.authorId // unresolved promise #1
  recipient: this.recipientId // unresolved promise #2
  // ... more promises here
  message: this.messageBody
}

let conn = this.pool.getConnection();
return conn.then((conn) => {
  const res = conn.query("INSERT INTO posts SET ?", [insertObj]);
  conn.release();
  return res
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `async/await`:

```
async function f() {
    // Prefix all promises with await
    let insertObj = {
        author: await this.authorId,
        recipient: await this.recipientId,
        // ... more promises here
        message: await this.messageBody
    }

    let conn = this.pool.getConnection();
    return conn.then((conn) => {
        const res = conn.query("INSERT INTO posts SET ?", [insertObj]);
        conn.release();
        return res;
    });
}
```

Without `async/await` you could do this:

```
let insertObj = {
    author: this.authorId,
    recipient: this.recipientId,
    // ... more promises here
    message: this.messageBody
};
// Replace promises by their promised values as soon as they resolve:
Object.entries(insertObj).forEach( ([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof Object(value).then === 'function') // it is a "thenable"
        value.then ( response => insertObj[key] = response );
});
// Wait for all of them to resolve
Promise.all(Object.values(insertObj)).then( _ => {
    let conn = this.pool.getConnection();
    return conn.then((conn) => {
        const res = conn.query("INSERT INTO posts SET ?", [insertObj]);
        conn.release();
        return res;
    });
});
```

Comment: Short and elegant. Out of curiosity, how would I go about using regular promises?

Comment: What do you mean with regular promises? Is `this.authorId` not a regular promise? Or do you mean: "how can I do this without `async/await`, but with `then`?"

Comment: Yes, "how can I do this without async/await, but with then". I'm trying to understand what async/await are doing under the hood.

Comment: I tried author: new Promise((resolve, reject) => { this.authorId.then(r => { resolve(r)}) })

Comment: No, that is a [promise constructor anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) and does not help you further. I added a section to my answer: the key is `Promise.all`.